# Disabling JACK in android compilation

Tags: android, android-source, android-jack-and-jill

Does anybody know how to completely disable jack while compiling AOSP (Master)?

I've always had problems with **jack**, so I've just always turned it off by adding `ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK := false` in *BoardConfig.mk* (when compiling CyanogenMod).
I'm now compiling aosp and it just seems to ignore this command.

Note: I'm not really trying to solve any **jack** related issues I have, I'm trying to turn it off.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the JACK without to change any code.

```
make ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK:=false
```

Just do it when making the entire Android Project.

The magic is in `build/make/combo/javac.mk`:

```
ifndef ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK
# Defines if compilation with jack is enabled by default.
ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK := true
endif
```

And `build/make/core/config.mk`:

```
ifeq ($(ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK),true)
DEFAULT_JACK_ENABLED:=full
else
DEFAULT_JACK_ENABLED:=
endif
```

And `build/make/core/clear_vars.mk`:

```
LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED:=DEFAULT_JACK_ENABLED
```

It also indicates why your modification in a local module is in vain.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to use AOSP tag to build instead of master branch. For example, latest released Marshmallow is **android-6.0.1_r43** tag.

So let's look at **clear_vars.mk** which is responsible for default values:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-6.0.1_r43/core/clear_vars.mk#110

> LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED:=$(DEFAULT_JACK_ENABLED) # '' (ie disabled), disabled, full, incremental

So you either have to override `LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED` per module in Android.mk **or** define global default value with `DEFAULT_JACK_ENABLED` variable.

P.S. It's better to ask such questions on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-building