# Adding jack library to build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have an android platform app that uses a legacy framework in the *build.gradle* file.

```
compile files('../../../out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.android.services.mycomponent.common_intermediates/classes.jar')
```

Now it is being ported to  different version of android that uses jack and the above dependency does not work.
I see no more see *classes.jar* in `out/../intermediates/` instead there is *classes.jack*.

Changing the dependency to `*.jack` in Gradle file is not helping either.

Please advise a better approach.
I cannot disable jack in the legacy service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680397/disabling-jack-in-android-compilation